# Cocoa: how to make a mini toolbar like finder?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Instead of using standard toolbar, I want to implement a Finder like toolbar, which using button as follow:

[image]

but my implementation looks weird.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do the buttons with the down arrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the "Round Textured" button style in Interface Builder.